# Synonym of 'Run' or 'Operate' in the context of a computer programme

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find the right word for this sentence, and replace the word *run* with something more computer orientated

> A bash script was developed to *run* the programme

I've looked on [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/run?) to no avail, and I am now turning to SE for help.

What word can I use to replace *run*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your context you may  use the verb "execute":

> A bash script was developed to execute the program.

Comment: And note it's usually program for computers, even in the UK where programme it's used for TV, theatre guides, etc.

Comment: @Hugo: Haha yes - in the UK, if we've recorded a tv program on the video, we might feasibly **play** it later (more likely **put it on**) when we want to watch it. We certainly wouldn't **run** it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *execute,* or *invoke.*

Answer (score 3):

I realise this answer may be downvoted because strictly speaking it's a comment, but it seems to me I need the chart to make my point. To wit, OP is simply mistaken in thinking that *"run"* somehow doesn't suit [the computer context](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20a%20computer%20program,execute%20a%20computer%20program&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

Regarding alternatives, @mustafa and @Incognito have both flagged up the most common *(execute)* - but *"run"* far outweighs even this, let alone rarer usages like *launch, invoke, open* etc.

Comment: The script in question is running the program for several iteration, each time executing the same piece of code, until a full run of executions is made. I think that phrasing makes more sense (as it does in my work), than *just* using run. Thanks for the graph though, I love nGrams +1!

Comment: @Pureferret: It's not obvious to me that *"The script in question is* **executing** *the program for several iterations, each time* **running** *the same piece of code"* is any less "natural". And *a full run of executions* seems a bit weird to me anyway - I'd probably just say *a full sequence*. But thanks for the upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about 'launch'? 'Start' is pleasingly mundane, too. 'Open' might be suitable for a user-level application, like iTunes. 'Activate' if there's a chance it's already running. I've never liked 'invoke' - it reeks of magic... :)

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." Hopefully that's what my program will be.